# inclusion of $\sigma$-algebra generated by random variables

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

Consider the following random variables
$$X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\quad\text{and}\quad Y:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$$
and
$$Z:=XY$$.

One may interpret it as follows, i.e.
$$Z(\omega) = X(\omega)Y(\omega).$$

In general, we cannot say much about the relations amongst $\sigma(X),\sigma(Y)$ and $\sigma(Z)$, as discussed in the answer below.

---

However, if we consider $X_i:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ for $i\in(\infty,\infty)$.

Why do we have $\sigma(\cdots,X_{n-1}X_n)\subsetneq \sigma(\cdots,X_n)$?

Comment: Nobody writes anything like $XY$ when $\Omega_1 \neq \Omega_2$ (hence "without confusion $Z$ is understood as..." is from your making). Later on, what is $X\times Y$ in $\sigma(X\times Y)$?

Comment: @Did updated the post.

Comment: I CAN say that $\sigma(Z) \subset \sigma(X,Y)$! Isn't that much?

Comment: Your notation for the last inclusion is clumsy. But you MIGHT have equality. It just doesn't happen always. To see one case equality doesn't hold, just take $X_n = \frac{1}{X_{n-1}}$.

Comment: @AndréCaldas How to show $\sigma(Z)\subset\sigma(X,Y)$?

Comment: @newbie Because Z is a measurable function of (X,Y) (this is quite general).

Comment: @Did Yes it is a general result. I am more interested in if the inclusion would be strict.

Comment: The inclusion is strict if Z does not determine (X,Y).

Comment: @Did how to show that for the case $Z = XY$?

Comment: New question? Then new post.

Comment: @Did That's not a new question. It's been included since beginning.

Comment: Where is it in the question? I cannot see it.

Comment: [if X=Y⋅ZX=Y⋅Z, then σ(X)⊆σ(Y,Z)σ(X)⊆σ(Y,Z). – saz Sep 21 at 14:18](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445065/prove-y-0-is-mathscrl-measurable#comment2943655_1445082)

Answer (score 0):

The first is valid. The second implies $\omega_1 = \omega_2$. It's valid too, but a waste of indices. You can imagine as if Tyche would choose a random point of  $\Omega$. This point is then mapped according to $X$ and $Y$ to two real numbers. Nothing particular follows from this for the relationship between $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$. You can construct both r.v., such that $\sigma(X) \subset \sigma(X)$ or identical or even $\sigma(Y) \cap \sigma(X) = \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$.

Concerning subset-relations between these $\sigma$-algebras, one can not say anything in general. Usually $\sigma(Z)$ is finer than $\sigma(X),\sigma(Y)$, but if e.g. $X(A)=0, Y(A^C)=0$, then $\sigma(Z)=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ and $\sigma(Z)$ is even coarser than the other algebras. It is possible, that $\sigma(Z) = \sigma(X \times Y) = \sigma(X,Y)$

Generally not possible is $Z:\Omega^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with your definition $Z(\omega)=X(\omega)Y(\omega)$. Your definition implies that the same chosen $\omega$ is mapped by $X$ and $Y$. The latter implies that Tyche may choose a tupel $(\omega_1, \omega_2) \in \Omega^2$, so $X$ and $Y$ may map two different points.

Comment: What is "the first"? And what is "the second"??? -- sorry... I see the OP changed the question.